# How to know last occurence of while loop

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, azure, loops

I have this piece of code where I am hitting an Azure REST API and it has `nextlink` in it which basically means that because the file is too large, it has nextlink as parameter with which it will again hit the API until the nextlink parameter does not come.

```
while 'nextLink' in json.loads(response.text)['properties']:
    total.extend(json.loads(response.text))
    req = requests.get(json.loads(response.text)['properties']['nextLink'], headers=head, verify=False)
    c+=1
    print(c)
    total.append(req.json())
```

THe problem is that I dont know how many times the while loop will run. But I wanted to end the loop before the last hit/occurence. The `c` is to know how many times it is running. Sometimes it runs for 80 times, sometimes for 200 times.

THe reason I wanted to know the last occurence-1 is that after the while loop I have an upload file statement which is not running if I dont give a break statement.

Comment: `c` will give you the number of times right?

Comment: @GodIsOne yeah it will give me total number of times after the loop is complete. I wanted something like if its going to run for 200 times, then at 199th time, it breaks automatically. Like breaking 1 step before the last occurence.

Answer (score 0):

You could add the previous req in each iteration.

```
req = None # used as previous
while 'nextLink' in json.loads(response.text)['properties']:
    total.extend(json.loads(response.text))
    if req is not None:
        total.append(req.json()) 
    req = requests.get(json.loads(response.text)['properties']['nextLink'], headers=head, verify=False)
    c+=1
    print(c)
```

Comment: Shouldn't `req` be after this `req = requests.get(json.loads(response.text)['properties']['nextLink'], headers=head, verify=False)`. Otherwise it will be referencing before initialization.

Comment: @PeakyBlinder, You are right, I also didn't need to use two variables for this.  I corrected the answer.